# issues when executing crontab job

Tags: python, cron, debian

i have a simple cron job that should sent mail every 15 minutes and update a local sqlite3 db file.
the problem is while i do get the mails correctly,the table in the db dose not get updated,

```
import sys
import Adafruit_DHT
import time
import sqlite3
import datetime
import smtplib

print('Fierd!')
print(datetime.datetime.now())
humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(Adafruit_DHT.DHT22, 17)
conn = sqlite3.connect('history.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS history(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,temp real,humidty integer,time DATE )''')
c.execute('''INSERT INTO history(temp,humidty,time) VALUES(?,?,?)''',(temperature,humidity,datetime.datetime.now()))
conn.commit()
conn.close()

server = smtplib.SMTP('*************',587)
server.starttls()
server.login('******','********')
msg =temperature
server.sendmail('*******************','******************',repr(msg))
server.quit()
```

as you can see the mail should be sent after the value was inserted to the db.
but i am only reciving the mails.
if i am running it manually it dose work as expected.

**EDIT:**
this is the cron command:
 */15 * * * * sudo python /home/pi/adafruit_python_DHT/examples/saveHistory.py &> /tmp/mycommand.log  # JOB_ID_1
any ideas ?

Comment: can you also share the crontab entry?

Comment: The probable issue here seems to be that `history.db` is being connected from another file location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of possible/likely problems going on here.

1. You should not have a sudo command in your crontab. this can and does cause problems. If you need to run a job with elevated privileges you need to add it to the sudo crontab `$ sudo crontab -e`
2. Your database in your code is just identified as history.db which implies it is in the same folder as your script. However, cron does NOT run in the files folder, it runs from the cron root directory. You have two options here:

   -- Probably best is to provide the absolute path to the database you want to load so that it can be found from any working directory

   --You can `import os` then do an `os.chdir()` to change the current working directory to the location of your database

Comment: Thanks ! 
did found another db file it in the root folder with all of the missing information from the past 2 days.